# how to save php code in database

Tags: php, database, eval

Currently I am working on a project in which I have to save `some PHP code` in database, I am saving the code with `PHP tags`.

But I am not getting how I can retrieve the code exactly as stored into database.

I have tried the following methods :

a) Direct retrieval : When I am retrieving the databse directly then the value of $row['code'] is blank

b) using eval() : When I am using eval() then I am getting syntax error :

`syntax error, unexpected '<' in H:\xampp\htdocs\trycodeonline\testing.php(27) : eval()'d code on line 1`

c) using eval()  without php tags : when I am removing the php codes then I am getting result instead of code, like I want to print `echo "hello"` but it is printing "hello"

So how can I print the php code ?

Comment: bad bad bad idea, please dont

Comment: Ohhh I get his idea now. It's basically a code sharing website like copepad.

Comment: yep Dave Chen thats exactly like codepad of jsfiddle

Comment: What does your database look like? Column `code` being blank is strange.

Comment: `I want to print echo "hello" but it is printing "hello"` then you should use `highlight_string` on it or something.

Comment: I am getting another idea instead of saving into database i am planning to save into files how it whould be ?

Comment: If you want files, you can just place them in a folder (not in your docroot), call them by a random name, and then store the name in the database. Then you can call them with PHP and display them.

Comment: yep i am doing the same, i am creating a md5 hash of a uniquid and saving the file with the same name, so is there any security issue ?

Comment: LOL, you are the security issue. Yes. Saving something else into another field does not make this more or less secure. The problem is, that you do stuff without understanding it. First understand. Then decide if you really want to use that. E.g. failing with eval albeit http://php.net/eval explains how it works can happen. However with all the warnings given to you, you should understand that *you* should not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do it, you can use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) as your method c) suggests:

```
$var // your variable with the data from the DB
<?php echo eval("?>". $var ."<?") ?>
```

There are many legitimate use-cases where you'll want to store PHP commands in a database, and I personally find shouting "dont do it" without knowing the circumstances a bit unhelpful.

Anyway, as has already been pointed out in various threads, there are security issues and other pitfalls using this approach and I would recommend against it. It will make debugging harder, and increases potential security vulnerabilities, and so on...

Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) post and [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/02/27/eval-is-dead-long-live-eval/) post to know more about the pitfalls of using eval().

Comment: Also not understanding PHP syntax and failing with the first application of `eval` should make one smell ones own enough to understand to keep fingers off this for the next years until totally sure how this works.

Answer (score 2):

highlight_string strings works fine

```
  $str=highlight_string('<?php
   echo "hello";
  ?>',true);
  echo $str;
```

Comment: but the main thing how can i retrieve the php code from database

Comment: @lord_linus save into the database with mysql_real_escape_string and stripslashes after getting from the database...

Answer (score 1):

Convert any non alphanumeric character to HTML equivalent (i.e whitespace to  ) then store it in your database. Then your query can straight outta wood use it in the View.

Comment: agree, you might want to use htmlentities function

Comment: Sorry tried to put `nbsp;` but shown as real empty space. But you got the idea

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not getting how I can retrieve the code exactly as stored into database.

Well, if you're not able to do that, please *ask a database question* (please after you've taken a PHP and database programming course). Because unless this works, the rest is a total different story anyway.